# Scala - Java = ? (Or Clojure - Java = ?)

Tags: java, scala, clojure

1. Is it possible for a developer to use Scala without knowing Java?
2. Is it possible for a developer to use Clojure without knowing Java?

Note: For example I am a C# developer and I use .NET without knowing any VB (Of-course WF 4.0 uses VB for statements, so I refuse any projects involving WF 4.0 :) ).

Summary I: Thanks to all for your answers. Now I can tell one can use these languages without knowing Java (The Language). Now I've got another question: How can one start with Java (JVM) ecosystem? What are beginner, intermediate and advanced knowledge-bases (bags!)? To be honest Java ecosystem was always a bit confusing to me, so it would be very helpful to provide some "reference references" and "defacto tutorials" for learning (curve!) JVM.
(OK! I will post it as another question!)

Comment: I had a Java background but found that you didn't really need it at all for Clojure until you get to the Java interop stuff. Even at that point Java is so close to C# that I don't think you'll have any trouble...

Comment: Have you considered the possibility of using f#? it's functional in a ML style with a rich type system (closer to scala than clojure then) and it is included out-of-the-box in .net

Comment: Thanks for mentioning F# and I am using F# happily in some projects. My problem is a new project - of course it is at early stages and may be totally abandoned - that will be developed on GAE (And I do not like Python and at the same time C# is Javaish enough - and to some extend more attractive than Java (for me) - so I heard about Scala and have read some tutorials and it is/seems very pragmatic and cool).

Comment: jum if you are programming against gae i think clojure have more documentation floating around internet (at least i have found more references: http://www.diigo.com/user/jneira/clojure%20appengine )

Comment: Can you provide a link to the new question?

Comment: The new question is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2993219/start-with-java-jvm-ecosystem

Thank you

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Scala, and Clojure even more so, are totally different languages from Java. The only thing they have in common is that they run on the Java virtual machine. You do not need to know the Java programming language to program in Scala or Clojure. It would be useful, however, to know something about the Java ecosystem (the Java virtual machine and runtime environment).

Comment: Clojure especially seems to attract people who don't know any Java. Leingingen makes things a lot easier for them than it used to be, but there are still a lot of useful things that will save you a lot of time that are available to you in Java.

Answer (score 4):

Sure you can. You'll lack the knowledge of the standard library at first, but that's not a big problem when you're starting with a new languages anyway. Clojure & Scala, however, put a heavy emphasis on the Java interop and do not try to hide the raw Java stuff, so you'd probably have to learn more about Java(not the language - the Java Platform) at some point to make maximum use of the language and the underlying platform.

Answer (score 3):

Speaking from the perspective of knowing Java and Clojure (but not Scala), you can use Clojure just fine without knowing Java. You have access to the core language, which is fully-featured, and libraries (e.g. clojure-contrib).

However, one of the big benefits of using Clojure (versus other lisps) is access to the Java ecosystem - libraries, debuggers, JVM, etc.

So, yes you can use Clojure effectively and I wouldn't let a lack of Java knowledge hinder you, but you'll add to your bag of tricks if you eventually start to learn enough Java to take advantage.

Comment: In my experience it's pretty easy for someone experienced in C# to pick up Java and vice-versa, they are very similar. So OP could probably leverage the C# experience a lot in picking up the Java libraries even if the only purpose was to use them from Clojure or Scala.

Answer (score 3):

Well, Clojure has been ported to the CLR. Probably easier thant the whole jump to the JVM since you are a .NET developer. :)

http://github.com/richhickey/clojure-clr

Comment: There is also Scala for the CLR, although it hasn't been maintained very well for some time.

Comment: cool, didn'tknow that :) well anything that runs on the JVM could potentially run on the CLR so no reason :)

Answer (score 1):

yes, thats me!

Has not been much of a problem for me except for when I needed a stupid simple swing gui. thats when I had to go back and review java.

Answer (score 0):

Scala is totally different language than java. So yes, you can of course use scala without knowing java ( but of course you have to learn scala first). Even though, knowing java (or any OO language) + some functional language makes it easier to understand scala.